# Multiple glyphs for network nodes in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Is there please a way to draw a network graph (generated by python networkx module) with multiple different glyphs (circle, rect...)?

So far I only found a way to have all the node glyphs same with just differing size and color using the "graph.node_renderer.glyph = something".

Thank you.

Comment: I'm also interested...did you get to know how to do it?

Comment: Hello, I am interested as well. Does any of you two found something ?

Comment: Hi, it is funny as I have just returned to my original project lately. Well, I ended up drawing different glyphs using another renderer over the original glyphs. So I have for instance triangles drawn over the circles.

Answer (score 0):

One way to give the nodes a different marker is by using the [Scatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.1/docs/reference/models/markers.html#scatter) glyph.

#### Part 1: Use Scatter glyph with marker attribute pointing to a data source

So, instead of

```py
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=20)
```

you could use also this to draw circles

```py
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Scatter(size=20, marker="circle")
```

You may use multiple different markers if you change the `marker` part to point to a data source (see below):

```
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Scatter(size=20, marker="marker")
```

The graph here is of type [bokeh.models.GraphRenderer](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/user_guide/graph.html).

#### Part 2: Add a data source which defines the markers for each node

Then, you need to add a data source for the "marker":

```py
# NOTE: make one item in `markers` per node in the graph (assuming 4-node graph) 
markers = ["circle", "square", "circle", "square"]
graph.node_renderer.data_source.add(markers, 'marker')
```

Alternatively, you might want to define the whole data source at once with a dictionary

```
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data = dict(
   # The 'index' is required by GraphRenderer. It must be a unique node identifier.
   index=node_ids,
   size=sizes,
   marker=markers
)
```

The different options for markers are listed in [bokeh.core.enums.MarkerType](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.1/docs/reference/core/enums.html#bokeh.core.enums.MarkerType) and are:

```
sterisk, circle, circle_cross, circle_dot, circle_x,

    circle_y, cross, dash, diamond, diamond_cross, diamond_dot, dot,

    hex, hex_dot, inverted_triangle, plus, square, square_cross,

    square_dot, square_pin, square_x, star, star_dot, triangle,

    triangle_dot, triangle_pin, x, y
```

Here's also a picture of the marker types from the Scatter documentation:

[image: marker-options-example]